# Printing linked list from binary search tree

Tags: java, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a program that has a binary search tree (Roster) that Student objects are inserted to by their String Id. Each student has a linked list that their  courses are added to containing the String of the course and their grade. The binary search tree is my own version of an implementation.

I'm having trouble implementing my method to print the students that all  contain a specific course. I think my implementation is off in my printCourse method as I can't call to it from my displayStudent() method under my Roster class. This is a homework assignment and I have most of the other methods implemented, just struggling with this one, any help is greatly appreciated!

> displayStudents("Math161");

is the method i'm correctly struggling to implement. It calls from the method in my roster class, which i'm trying to implement to search through my BST

In my BST the method printCourse() should check each students linked list and if it contains the course listed above and print each student that does. Here's what I have so far, which is not correct:

```
> public void printCourse(Node n, String course) { 
>         if (n != null) {
>             inOrder(n);
>             if (n.element.getId().equals(course)) { 
>                 System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
>             }
>         }
>     }
```

Homework5.class / Main:

```
public class Homework5 {

    static Roster rost = new Roster();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addStudent();
        displayAllStudents();
        lookupStudent("11114");
        addCourse();
        displayStudents("Math161");

    }

    // add students to the roster
    static void addStudent() {
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11111", "Jon", "Benson"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11112", "Erick", "Hooper"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11113", "Sam", "Shultz"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11114", "Trent", "Black"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11115", "Michell", "Waters"));
        rost.addStudent(new Student("11116", "Kevin", "Johnson"));
    }

    // display all students in the roster
    static void displayAllStudents() {
        rost.displayAllStudents();
    }

    // lookup a student in the roster
    static void lookupStudent(String id) {
        if (rost.find(id) != null) {
            System.out.println(id + " found");
        } else {
            System.out.println(id + " not found");
        }
    }

    // add courses to the roster
    static void addCourse() {
        rost.addCourse("11111", new Course("CS116", 80));
        rost.addCourse("11111", new Course("Math161", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("Math161", 70));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("CS146", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11112", new Course("CS105", 85));
        rost.addCourse("11113", new Course("CS216", 90));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("CIS255", 75));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("CS216", 80));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("Math161", 60));
        rost.addCourse("11114", new Course("COMM105", 90));
    }

    // display students enrolled in a given course id
    static void displayStudents(String courseId) {
        rost.displayStudents(courseId);
    }
}
```

Student.class:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    LinkedList<Course> courses = new LinkedList<>();

    Student(String id, String fName, String lName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setName(String lName) {
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student other) {    
        return this.getId().compareTo(other.getId());
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.add(course);
    }

}
```

Course.class:

```
class Course {

    LinkedList<Course> course = new LinkedList<>();

    String id;  // course id
    int grade;

    Course(String id, int grade) {
        this.id = id;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setId(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

}
```

Roster.class:

```
class Roster {

    Student root;
    int numStudents;

    BST<Student> roster = new BST<>();
    LinkedList<Course> courseList = new LinkedList<>();

    public Roster() {
        root = null;
        numStudents = 0;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student st) {
        roster.insert(st);
        numStudents++;
    }

    public void displayAllStudents() {
        roster.traverse(2);
    }

    public Student find(String id) {
        return roster.find(id);
    }

    public void addCourse(String id, Course course) {
        Student student = roster.find(id);
        student.addCourse(course);      
    }

    public void displayStudents(String courseId) {
        roster.printCourse(courseId);
    }
}
```

BST.java

```
class BST<Roster extends Comparable> {

    private Node root;

    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }

    // Generic find method
    public Student find(String id) {

        Node current = root;

        while (id.compareTo(current.element.getId()) != 0) {
            if (id.compareTo(current.element.getId()) < 0) {
                current = current.left;
            } 
            else {
                current = current.right;
            }
            if (current == null) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return current.element;

    }

    public void insert(Student st) {
        Node newNode = new Node(st);

        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
        } else {
            Node current = root;
            Node parent = null;

            while (true) {
                parent = current;
                if (st.getId().compareTo(current.element.getId()) < 0) {
                    current = current.left;
                    if (current == null) {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    current = current.right;
                    if (current == null) {
                        parent.right = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printCourse(Node n, String course) { 
        if (n != null) {
            inOrder(n);
            if (n.element.getId().equals(course)) { 
                System.out.print(n.element.getId() + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    public void traverse(int traverseType) {
        switch (traverseType) {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("\nPreorder traversal: ");
                // call preOrder(root) and implement preOrder()
                preOrder(root);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nList of all students:  ");
                inOrder(root);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nPostorder traversal: ");
                // call postOrder(root) and implement postOrder()
                postOrder(root);
                break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private void inOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            inOrder(localRoot.left);
            System.out.print(localRoot.element.getId() + " ");
            inOrder(localRoot.right);
        }
    }

    private void preOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
            preOrder(localRoot.left);
            preOrder(localRoot.right);
        }
    }

    private void postOrder(Node localRoot) {
        if (localRoot != null) {
            postOrder(localRoot.left);
            postOrder(localRoot.right);
            System.out.print(localRoot.element + " ");
        }
    }

}

class Node {

    protected Student element;
    protected Node left;
    protected Node right;

    public Node(Student st) {
        element = st;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is everything, but two things that I see that seem wrong are:

1. In the Roster.class: The roster.printCourse(courseId) call in displayStudents() only includes one parameter, the courseId, but the printCourse() method in BST.java has two parameters, a Node and a String.
2. In the Roster.class: The BST called roster is given a type `<Student>`, but the definition of BST in BST.java has it containing a Roster, not a Student. Note: You don't need to use <> with a type inside unless that type can change. If BST can only be applied to the type Student, then you don't need that in the definition or the creation of BST. On the other hand, if your BST should work for any type of data, you should define the BST as class BST `<T extends Comparable>` and make sure to use T wherever the type should go. (Look up Generic Types on Google for more examples.)